# c++ print number in hexadecimal right after floor function

Tags: c++, hex, cout, floor

I've noticed some weird behaviour in c++ which i don't understand,
i'm trying to print a truncated double in a hexadecimal representation

this code output is **17** which is a decimal representation

```
double a = 17.123;
cout << hex << floor(a) << '\n';
```

while this code output is **11** and also my **desirable output**

```
double a = 17.123;
long long aASll = floor(a);
cout << hex << aASll << '\n';
```

as double can get really big numbers i'm afraid of wrong output while storing the truncated number in long long variable, any suggestions or improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quoting CPPreference's documentation page for `std::hex` (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)

> Modifies the default numeric base for integer I/O.

This suggests that `std::hex` does not have any effect on floating point inputs. The best you are going to get is

```
cout << hex << static_cast<long long>(floor(a)) << '\n';
```

or a function that does the same.

`uintmax_t` from `<cstdint>` may be useful to get the largest available integer  if the values are always positive. After all, what is a negative hex number?

Since a `double` value can easily exceed the maximum resolution of available integers, this won't cover the whole range. If the floored values exceed what can fit in an integer type, you are going to have to do the conversion by hand or use a big integer library.

Side note: `std::hexfloat` does [something very different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and does not work correctly in all compilers due to some [poor wording in the current Standard](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2381) that is has since been hammered out and should be corrected in the next revision.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own version of floor and have it return an integral value.  For example:

```
long long floorAsLongLong(double d)
{
  return (long long)floor(d);
}

int main() {
  double  a = 17.123;
  cout << hex << floorAsLongLong(a) << endl;
}
```